# Register not working

Tags: php

I have made a login page and entered the information into the database manually and the login page works perfectly fine.

I have made this register page but when i click the button it just makes a white page and dont even bring me a error but i think i have outlined all the possible errors there could be?

Here is my register.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start(); 
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> StormZ - Register </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if ( $_POST['registerbtn']){
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if ($getuser){
        if ($getemail){
            if ($getpass){
                if ($getretypepass){
                    if ($getpass === $getretypepass){
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))){
                            require("./connect.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                            if ($numrows == 0){
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                                if ($numrows == 0){

                                    $password = md5(md5("130498".$password."K3iLlEn"));
                                    $date = date("F d, Y");
                                    $code = md5(rand());

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                                        '', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date'
                                    )");

                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if ($numrows == 1){

                                        $site = "http://********************";
                                        $webmaster = "*** <***@*********>";
                                        $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                        $subject = "Activate your account!";
                                        $message = "Thanks for registering please click the link below to activate your account.\n";
                                        $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                        $message .= "You must activate your account to login.";

                                        if ( mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
                                            $errormsg = "You have been registered, an email has been sent to $getemail click the link sent to you to activate your account.";
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }
                                        else
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured please try again later.";

                                    }
                                    else
                                        $errormsg = "An error has occured please try again later.";
                                }
                                else 
                                    $errormsg = "There is already a user with that Email.";
                            }
                            else 
                                $errormsg = "There is already a user with that username.";

                            mysql_close();
                        }
                        else
                            $errormsg = "The email you enetered wasnt in the correct format.";
                    }
                    else
                        $errormsg = "The passwords you enetered are not the same.";
                }
                else
                    $errormsg = "You must retype your password to register.";
            }
            else
                $errormsg = "You must enter a password to register.";
        }
        else
            $errormsg = "You must enter a email to register.";
    }
    else
        $errormsg = "You must enter a username to register.";
}
else




$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>$errormsg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$getemail' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='password' value='' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";

echo $form;
?>
</body>
```

Has anyone got any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: because you're not outputting anything if everything is successful

Comment: I thought i was with:                                        if ( mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
                                            $errormsg = "You have been registered, an email has been sent to $getemail click the link sent to you to activate your account.";
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }

Comment: no because you only ever show your form if the $_POST isn't set.

Comment: First your script looks ugly being written in a old procedural form. To a first view it is not clear where the message is displayed when recording is done.

Comment: Agreed, you should really considering rewriting all of this

Comment: How should i rewrite it all then? ANy good up to date tutorials?

Comment: You have a floating `else` in there with nothing after it. Remove it.

Comment: Start with a modern database API like PDO or mysqli to get rid of the sql injection problem you have now. Also display all errors **and** warnings and use a modern hashing algorithm with a unique salt for you passwords. And separate the php from the html.

Comment: and the rest of your `else`s dont have a `{` after them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `else` in your code , and replace it by a condition on `$errormsg` if it contain something then print it else if `$_POST['registerbtn']` is set then print a successful registration message .

By the way your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection , use [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) instead of what you are using here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong but I want to make a suggestion to get rid of the massive if else stuff:

```
try {
    if (something is wrong) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('x is wrong');
    }
    if (something something else is wrong) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('y is wrong');
    }
    // repeat this
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo 'There was an error while trying to register: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then for the procedural stuff.. use objects in the meaning of business logic:

For registration:

```
$user = new User() {
$user->setMail('...')
     ->setUsername('danfromgermany')
     ->setPassword('test')
     ->setHomepage('http://blog.flowl.info');

try {
    $user->register($database);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //something went wrong.. check $e->getMessage();
}
```

For login (same class):

```
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername('danfromgermany')
     ->setPassword('test');

try {
    if ($user->login($database)) {
        echo $user->getHomepage();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //something went wrong.. check $e->getMessage();
}
```

A class could look like this:

```
class User {
    protected $username;
    protected $mail;
    protected $password;
    protected $homepage;

    public function __construct() { }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername($username) {
        return $username;
    }

    // Repeat getter setter for other member variables

    // for password for example:
    public function getPassword() {
        throw new Exception('you may not get the password!');
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = CryptAndSaltAndStuff($password);
    }

    public function login(PDO $db) {
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name LIMIT 1");
        $statement->execute(array(':name' => $this->getUsername()));
        $row = $statement->fetch();
        if ($row->username == $this->getUsername() && $row->password == $this->password) {
            // make all data available in the class:
            $this->setHomepage($row->homepage);

            // you could query the database here again to set a "last login" DateTime!
            return true;
        } else {
            // You could query the database here to register a false login!
            return false;
        }
    }

    // same with register... but when success, you set the $this-> properties to the database values

}
```